# Robocopy using Powershell issue

Tags: powershell, syntax, robocopy

I am trying to copy some files inside a Powershell script using Robocopy.

Here is my script.

```
$serial = Get-CimInstance win32_bios
$mdtserver = "\\TESTMDT01\"
$cmd = "robocopy.exe"
$arg = "/MIR"
$source = """C:\Program Files\HPIALogs"""
$destination = '"' + $mdtserver + "HPIALogs$\" + $serial.SerialNumber + '"'
   
Start-Process -wait $cmd $source $destination $arg
```

The problem is when I run the script I get the following error:

> Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '"\\TESTMDT01\HPIALogs$\CZCxxx88QW"'

As a test if I run the command:

```
Write-Host $cmd $source $destination $arg
```

...it outputs the following string which looks correct and when copied into a command window runs?

> robocopy.exe "C:\Program Files\HPIALogs" "\\TESTMDT01\HPIALogs$\CZCxxx88QW" /MIR

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: `Start-Process $cmd -wait -ArgumentList $source,$destination,$arg`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you, that fixed my issue. If you can add as an Answer, Ill mark it as being correct.